# Error replacing xml file @C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xpath, console-application

I am writing a console application where I'm trying to replace a xml file (`xx.config`) with other xml file(`xx.config`) which is at different folder with different data to the path `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell`.
I'm getting following error

> Could not find a part of the path `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\xx.config`

But there is the file at this path. I tried to load this file to `XMLDocument` then also same error occurred. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

> XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test\xx.config");\loads good
> XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\xx.config");\error occurs
>
> File.Move(@"C:\test\xx.config", >@"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\xx.config");\error occurs

Comment: Try running as administrator?

Comment: I'm running as administrator but getting error